# scope of functions in webpack modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have some functions in a webpack module but they can't call each other? How do I import a function A in a webpack module for use in a function B in the same webpack module?

For example:

```
module.exports = {
 handlerror: function(msg) {
    alert(msg)
 }


 init_session: function(key, session_id) {
        var session = init(key,session_id)
        if (session == "fail") { handlerror("failed") }
        return session;
    }
}
```

In this scenario the runtime complains about handlerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function by itself first so you can reference its standalone name in the body of the code, and put it into `module.exports` separately:

```
function handlerror(msg) {
  alert(msg)
}
module.exports = {
  handlerror
  // other exports
};

// reference handlerror as needed here
```

Note that you might consider changing the name to `handleError` (or something like it) to correct the spelling and make it more readable.